# Express-session works wrong when website migrated from http to https?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, https, express-session

After we migrated our website from http scheme to https (including enabling https on CDN and redirecting http to https on server), we found that our user sessions works incorrectly sometimes, that is, the user A would be recognized as user B! It seems the session ids of cookies are incorrectly parsed and maybe different users share the same cookies or session ids but all the session ids are generated by uid-safe uniquely.

The issue seems very strange and we really have no idea of the cause.

we use nodejs, Express, express-session with redis storage.

The express-session setup is as below:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'xxxx',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 3600*24*90*1000
  },
  store: new redisStore(),
  resave: false,
  rolling: true,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

Comment: Show code. For instance, your `express-session` setup.

Comment: @robertklep the `express-session` setup is added. Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you testing those different users from within the same browser? Also, do you have some sort of reverse proxy in front of Node that may be causing the issue (for instance, it's caching pages without sending a `Vary` response header)?

Comment: @robertklep we haven't tested that since it's hard to reproduce. Till now, we inspect the issue from log. And we don't have reverse proxy but we do have CDN. We have indeed observed before that the CDN cached the 301 redirecting response though it will not cache any other dynamic response. So if it's possible that CDN sends last user's cookie to the next one and update latter when redirecting from http to https? But redirecting by nginx would not send cookie header...

Comment: I would think that if the CDN is merely redirecting a user from `http://` to `https://` it will not set any cookies (I also assume that your server is setting the session cookies, not the CDN). If you can see the issue appearing in the logfile, can you see them having the same session id value? If so, you should query your database to see if there are indeed multiple sessions attached to the same session id.

Comment: @robertklep we finally found that our website icons are sent back via express-static other than nginx which would take cookies back along. And in the migration, we had changed our CDN service provider. The new CDN will cache the static files even containing cookie headers which would not be cached before. So we believe it's caused by the new CDN and has nothing with HTTPS till now. we basically reproduced the error case. Thanks for you inspiration. BTW, totally disabling express-static in production environment should be the best practice.

Comment: You should look into sending back the `Vary` header from your server to the CDN, with which you can tell it that it shouldn't cache responses that contain specific headers (like `Set-Cookie`).